# Dynamic Where for List<T>

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I'm trying to create a dynamic filter for various classes.  We would only know at runtime what type we're dealing with. I need the ColumnName to be the actual column (not a string value).

Is there an easy way to convert the string into a column?

```
public static List<T> Filter<T>
    (this List<T> Source, string ColumnName, 
    string TypeOfCompare, string CompValue)
{
    IQueryable<T> matches = Source.AsQueryable();

    if (ColumnName.Length > 0)
    {
        matches = (IEnumerable)matches.Where(a => ColumnName == CompValue)
    }

    List<T> ReturnList2 = new List<T>();
    ReturnList2 = matches.ToList();
    return ReturnList2;
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Basically you need to build an expression tree. It's not terribly hard, fortunately, using [`Expression.Property`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341554.aspx). You can either pass that to `Queryable.Where`, or compile it and pass it to `Enumerable.Where`. (Obviously you'll need to use something like [`Expression.Equal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.equal.aspx) 
as well, depending on the type of comparison you're trying to make.)

Is `CompValue` meant to be an actual value? What's `TypeOfCompare` meant to be?

I'm not sure where LINQ to Entities fits into this, either... you're only using LINQ to Objects really, as far as I can see.

EDIT: Okay, here's a sample. It assumes you want equality, but it does what you want if so. I don't know what the performance impact of compiling an expression tree every time is - you may want to cache the delegate for any given name/value combination:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

static class Extensions
{
    public static List<T> Filter<T>
        (this List<T> source, string columnName, 
         string compValue)
    {
        ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
        Expression property = Expression.Property(parameter, columnName);
        Expression constant = Expression.Constant(compValue);
        Expression equality = Expression.Equal(property, constant);
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate =
            Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(equality, parameter);

        Func<T, bool> compiled = predicate.Compile();
        return source.Where(compiled).ToList();
    }
}

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var people = new[] {
            new { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Smith" },
            new { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Noakes" },
            new { FirstName = "Linda", LastName = "Smith" },
            new { FirstName = "Richard", LastName = "Smith" },
            new { FirstName = "Richard", LastName = "Littlejohn" },
        }.ToList();

        foreach (var person in people.Filter("LastName", "Smith"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(person);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Right... it's Linq to Objects... We have classes containing data like (firstname, lastname, phone) and CompValue is the actual value that we're looking to match...so an example would be...

personCollection = personCollection.Filter("LastName", "Smith");

And we'd be returning the "filtered" collection of Smiths...

Thanks

Comment: Perfect... Thanks Jon.

John K.

Comment: I think it would be better if you change type of parameter compValue from 'string' to 'object', in case you need to Equal integers or strings. public static List<T> Filter<T>
        (this List<T> source, string columnName, 
         object compValue)

Comment: @Delmonte: I was taking the signature from the question. I'd quite possibly make it more generic (add a type parameter) rather than accepting just object.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a string `ColumnName`, can't you pass a selector for that column (I realize this isn't always possible, but just in case it is …)? This you could use, then.

By the way, the code is way too complicated. This should work:

```
public static List<T> Filter<T>(
    this List<T> Source, Func<T, string> selector, string CompValue)
{
    return Source.Where(a => selector(a) == CompValue).ToList();
}
```

You could then call the code as follows:

```
var result = myList.Filter(x => x.ColumnName, "foo");
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this: http://naspinski.net/post/Writing-Dynamic-Linq-Queries-in-Linq-to-Entities.aspx
 Otherwise you have to handle each case separately like in the following:

```
if (columnName == "blah")
  matches = matches.Where(i => i.Blah == Value);
if (columnName == "name")
  matches = matches.Where(i => i.Name == Value);
```

Comment: what if my **matches** variable is of type dynamic list of Run time Type ?